# Return multiple match values in one cell of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there any function in R which compares values in a data frame to another and returns multiple matching values in a single cell of a data frame? `match()` (similar to `vlookup()` in EXCEL) returns the first matching value. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve using `dt1` and get `dt2`:

```
    animal <- c("Dog","Dog","Duck","Duck","Duck","Mouse","Mouse","Pig","Pig","Pig")
    name <- c("Tim","Brown","Jack","Harry","Jack","Tom","Sal","Jack","Tim","Don")
    age <- c(4,6,2,3,6,1,2,2,3,3)
    dt1 <- data.frame(animal,name,age)
```

---

I want to generate a new data frame which looks like dataframe, `dt2` as below:

```
    animal <- c("Dog","Duck","Mouse", "Pig")
    NumberofUniqueNames <- c(2,2,2,3)
    Names <- c("Tim, Brown", "Jack, Harry", "Tom, Sal", "Jack, Tim, Don")
    dt2 <- data.frame(animal,NumberofUniqueNames,Names)
```

[image: example]

I searched SO and in google and found something similar for EXCEL but not anything for R.

Some examples for EXCEL are [here](http://thinketg.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/) and [here](http://thinketg.com/say-goodbye-to-vlookup-and-hello-to-index-match/).

Comment: OR just `aggregate(name ~ animal, dt1, function(x) c(length(unique(x)), toString(x)))` or `library(data.table) ; setDT(dt1)[, .(uniqueN(name), toString(name)), by = animal]` Or `library(dplyr) ; dt1 %>% group_by(animal) %>% summarise(uniqueN(name), toString(name))`

Comment: Don't `cbind(...)` vectors of mixed types, just use `data.frame(...)`

Comment: To anyone else who is eager to add [tag:rstudio] and [tag:plyr] - please DON'T, it has nothing to do with the question and one does *not* adjust someones question according his own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
animal <- c("Dog","Dog","Duck","Duck","Duck","Mouse","Mouse","Pig","Pig","Pig")
name <- c("Tim","Brown","Jack","Harry","Jack","Tom","Sal","Jack","Tim","Don")
age <- c(4,6,2,3,6,1,2,2,3,3)
dt1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(animal,name,age))
View(dt1)

dt2 = ddply(dt1, .(animal), summarise, length(unique(name)), paste(unique(name), collapse = ", "))
View(dt2)

> dt2
  animal ..1            ..2
1    Dog   2     Tim, Brown
2   Duck   2    Jack, Harry
3  Mouse   2       Tom, Sal
4    Pig   3 Jack, Tim, Don
```

Comment: you can do the `data.frame` a bit cleaner since you already have column vectors. Rather than the `cbind` you can

    dt1 <- data.frame("animal" = animal, 
                      "name" = name,
                      "age" = age)

and you can also take advantage of this to get rid of factors, for example.

    dt1 <- data.frame("animal" = animal, 
                      "name" = name,
                      "age" = age,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

have a look at `?data.frame` for more options.